# How to open Word template, update some text, and save as .pdf in vb.net core

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-core, ms-word

I am working on a vb.net core console app that queries data from a database into a DataTable, opens a Word (.dot) template file, updates some text, and then saves as a .pdf without saving changes to the original template. Word is being very fussy. While debugging, if an exception is thrown, by the time I get to the catch block the Word.Application is gone, so I can't seem to exit gracefully, and apparently an instance is maintained in memory, as I have to reboot my machine to get the program to run again as Word won't start.

Is there a better way to interact with Word?

Here's my code:

```
Dim application As Word.Application = Nothing
Try
    application = New Word.Application With {.Visible = True}
    application.Documents.Open("C:\MattsFunctionReport.dot")
    Dim document = application.ActiveDocument
    
    'There are lots of these Items, just showing one as an example.                    
    If IsDBNull(row.Item("FunctionName"))
        document.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="<<FunctionName>>", ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
    Else
        document.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="<<FunctionName>>", ReplaceWith:=row.Item("FunctionName"), Replace:=WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
    End If

    'save as PDF
    application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2("C:\SampleOutput.pdf", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)

    'Close the document.
    application.Documents.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)

    'Quit Word.Application
    application.Quit()
Catch ex As Exception
    'Close Word
    application.Documents.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
    application.Quit()
    'Show Exception
    ConsoleEx.WriteError(ex.Message)
    ConsoleEx.WriteLineInRed(ex.StackTrace)
    'Log Exception
    WriteLog(ex.ToString)
    Console.Writeline("Press any key to exit the program.")
    Console.ReadKey()
    End
End Try
```

This is the exception I get when I try to debug again without rebooting.

[image: Exception StackTrace]

This is the exception when application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs("C:\SampleOutput.pdf", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)blows up..

[image: Other Exception]

Comment: Most likely not an answer to your question: but you should use `dim doc as word.document | set doc= application.Documents.Add("C:\MattsFunctionReport.dot")` and then `doc.SaveAs2 ...` and `doc.close false`

Comment: Tip: When MS Word crashes like this during interop, just open Task Manager and kill the Word task instead of rebooting your PC.

Comment: You'd need to make sure you're discarding your com objects fully. Closing the application should happen in the Finally block, not the exception block. To export as PDF have a look at the ExportAsFixedFormat method with param ExportFormat wdExportFormatPDF. I find it useful to record a macro in Word with what I'm trying to do, and then inspect the VBA for hints/usage.

Comment: Do not **open** the .dot or .dotx file. Create a ***new*** document using that as the template. `MyDoc = Documents.Add (Template:= "Your template full name and path")` After your pdf conversion, you can close this new document without saving it. That is the nature of template files in Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following shows how to open a `.dot` (or `.dotx`) Word template using Word interop in a .NET Console App, replace some text, and then export (ie: save) it as a PDF. For testing, I used .NET 6.

Try the following:

**Add reference**:

- Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library (ex: Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library)

**Add the following Imports statement**:

- Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

**ModifyWordDoc**:

```
Private Function ModifyWordDoc(filename As String, pdfFilename As String, Optional isVisible As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application = Nothing
    Dim document As Word.Document = Nothing

    Try
        'create new instance
        wordApp = New Word.Application() With {.Visible = isVisible}

        'create new document from template
        document = wordApp.Documents.Add(Template:=filename)

        'ToDo: add desired code

        document.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="<<FunctionName>>", ReplaceWith:="TEST", Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)

        'export (ie: save) as PDF
        document.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfFilename, Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF)

        Return "Successfully completed"
    Catch ex As Exception
        'ToDo: add desired code

        Debug.WriteLine($"Error (ModifyWordDoc) - {ex.Message}")
    Finally
        If document IsNot Nothing Then
            document.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
        End If

        If wordApp IsNot Nothing Then
            wordApp.Quit()
        End If
    End Try

    Return "Unsuccessful"
End Function
```

**Note**: You may desire to return an Integer instead of a String.

**Usage**:

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim filename As String = "C:\Temp\Test.dot"
    Dim pdfFilename As String = "C:\Temp\Test.pdf"
    Console.WriteLine($"Modifying Word document '{filename}'...")

    Dim result As String = ModifyWordDoc(filename, pdfFilename, True)
    Debug.WriteLine($"result: {result}")

    If result = "Successfully completed" Then
        Environment.Exit(0)
    Else
        Environment.Exit(-1)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Resources**:

- [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word?view=word-pia)
- [Documents.Add(Object, Object, Object, Object) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.add?view=word-pia#microsoft-office-interop-word-documents-add(system-object@-system-object@-system-object@-system-object@))
- [Document.ExportAsFixedFormat method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat)
- [WdExportFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdexportformat)
- [Printing pdf through automating word with VB net without showing dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71496417/printing-pdf-through-automating-word-with-vb-net-without-showing-dialog)

Comment: Do not **open** the .dot or .dotx file. Create a ***new*** document using that as the template. `MyDoc = Documents.Add (Template:= "Your template full name and path")` After your pdf conversion, you can close this new document without saving it. That is the nature of template files in Word.