# how can i find and replace text in .docx(Microsoft word file) using Interop

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, ms-word

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrOwD.png)
i wanna open a docx file and replacing a specific word that i want.
for example i wanna change A with B for all the texts inside the word file..

i have no idea for this... please help me.. thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to [include code as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71649599/10024425

Answer (score 1):

Hey you are already halfway there. In your example you opend the doc

```
Document docs = word.Documents.Open("path/file.docx");
```

Now we need to replace the text

```
docs.Content.Find.Execute(FindText: "oldtext", ReplaceWith: "newtext", Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, Missing: System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

docs.Save();
docs.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
```